# unable to print in protected mode

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, gnu-assembler, osdev

I am following these tutorial in os development [link1](https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/tree/master/13-kernel-barebones)
[link2](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples)

I am not able to print in protected mode.

here is my code:

```
$ gcc -E boot.S 
# 1 "boot.S"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "boot.S"
# 1 "header.h" 1



read_fail:
 .asciz "Disk read failed"

.altmacro

.macro PUSHA
 push %ax
 push %bx
 push %cx
 push %dx

.endm

.macro POPA
 pop %ax
 pop %bx
 pop %cx
 pop %dx
.endm

.macro PUSH_EA
 push %eax
 push %ebx
 push %ecx
 push %edx
.endm

.macro POP_EA
 pop %eax
 pop %ebx
 pop %ecx
 pop %edx
.endm

.macro CLEAR

 PUSH_EA
 mov $0x0600, %ax
 mov $0x07, %bh
 mov $0x00, %cx
 mov $0x184f, %dx
 int $0x10
 CURSOR_POS

 POP_EA
.endm

.macro CURSOR_POS x=2, y=2
 PUSH_EA
 mov $0x02, %ah
 mov $0x00, %bh
 mov \x, %dh
 mov \y, %dl
 int $0x10
 POP_EA


.endm

.macro BEGIN
 .code16
_start:
 xor %ax,%ax
 mov %ax, %ds
 mov %ax, %es
 mov %ax, %fs
 mov %ax, %gs
 mov %ax, %ss

 mov %ax, %bp
 mov %bp, %sp

.endm

.macro PRINT_STRING str

 LOCAL loop,end
 mov \str, %si
 mov $0x0E, %ah

 cld

loop:
 lodsb

 cmp $0x00, %al
 je end

 int $0x10
 jmp loop

end:
.endm

.macro HEX_NIBBLE reg
 LOCAL end, letter
 cmp $10, \reg
 jae letter
 add $'0', \reg
 jmp end

letter:
 add $0x37, \reg
.endm

.macro HEX c
 mov \c, %al
 mov \c, %ah
 shr $4, %al
 HEX_NIBBLE <%al>
 and $0x0F, %al
 HEX_NIBBLE <%ah>
.endm

.macro PRINT_CHAR c=$0x20
 push %ax
 mov \c, %al
 mov $0x0E, %ah
 int $0x10
 pop %ax

.endm

.macro PRINT_HEX reg=<%al>
 push %ax
 HEX <\reg>
 PRINT_CHAR <%al>
 PRINT_CHAR <%ah>
 pop %ax
.endm

.macro RESET_DISK

 LOCAL error,end

 mov $0x00, %ah
 mov $0x80, %dl
 int $0x13

 jmp end
end:
.endm



.macro STAGE2

 LOCAL read_error, end

 RESET_DISK

 mov $__stage2_nsectors, %al
 mov $0x9000, %ebp
 mov %ebp, %esp
 mov $0x02, %ah
 mov $0x0002, %cx
 mov $0x80, %dl
 mov $0x00, %dh
 mov $0x1000, %bx


 int $0x13
 jc read_error
 jmp 1f


read_error:
 PRINT_STRING $read_fail


 .section .stage2
1:
 jmp *(0x1000)
.endm



.macro PROTECTED_MODE



 .equ CODE_SEG, 8
 .equ DATA_SEG, gdt_data - gdt_start

 cli
 lgdt gdt_descriptor
 mov %cr0, %eax
 orl $0x01, %eax
 mov %eax, %cr0

 ljmp $CODE_SEG, $protected_mode

gdt_start:
gdt_null:
 .long 0x00
 .long 0x00

gdt_code:
 .word 0xFFFF
 .word 0x0000
 .byte 0x00
 .byte 0b10011010
# 220 "header.h"
 .byte 0b11001111
# 230 "header.h"
 .byte 0x00

gdt_data:
 .word 0xffff
 .word 0x00
 .byte 0x00
 .byte 0b10010010
 .byte 0b11001111
 .byte 0x00
gdt_end:
gdt_descriptor:
 .word gdt_end - gdt_start
 .long gdt_start


.code32
protected_mode:
 mov $DATA_SEG, %ax
 mov %ax, %ds
 mov %ax, %es
 mov %ax, %fs
 mov %ax, %gs
 mov %ax, %ss

 mov $0x9000, %ebp
 mov %ebp, %esp


.endm


vga_current_line:
 .long 0

.macro VGA_PRINT_STR str
 LOCAL loop,end

 PUSH_EA

 mov \str, %ecx
 mov vga_current_line, %eax

 mov $0, %edx
 mov $25, %ebx
 div %ebx
 mov %edx, %eax
 mov $160, %edx
 mul %edx


 lea 0xb8000(%eax), %edx
 mov $0x0f, %ah


loop:
 mov (%ecx), %al
 cmp $0, %al
 je end

 mov %ax, (%edx)
 inc %ecx
 addl $2, %edx
 jmp loop


end:
 POP_EA
 incl vga_current_line

.endm
# 2 "boot.S" 2


.section .text

 BEGIN
 CLEAR
 STAGE2
 PROTECTED_MODE
 VGA_PRINT_STR $str
 jmp .

str:
 .asciz "Hello"
```

Makefile

```
.POSIX:

IMAGE ?= $(FILENAME)
LD ?= ld
LD_SCRIPT ?= linker.ld
HEADER ?=header.h
GAS ?= gcc
CFLAGS ?= -c
QEMU ?= qemu-system-i386
OUT_EXT ?= .bin


all: $(IMAGE)$(OUT_EXT)

$(IMAGE).bin: $(IMAGE).o
    $(LD) -T'$(LD_SCRIPT)' --oformat=binary '$<' -o '$@'

$(IMAGE).o : $(IMAGE).S $(HEADER) 
    $(GAS) -c '$<' -o '$@'

run: $(IMAGE)$(OUT_EXT)
    $(QEMU) '$<'

clean: 
    rm *.o *bin
```

linker.ld

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32_i386");
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7c00;
    .text : {
        __start = .;
        *(.text)

        . = 0x1FE;
        SHORT(0xaa55);

        *(.stage2 )

        __stage2_nsectors = ABSOLUTE((. - __start)/512);

        . = ALIGN(512);
        __end = . ;
        __end_align_4k = ALIGN(4K);
    }
}
```

I am using qemu as an emulator. In Qemu, "Hello" should have been displayed, but this is the output.
[image: output in qemu]

I am unable to resolve this issue. Any pointers on this issue is appreciated.

- note : code works when bx register is set to $1f in .macro STAGE2 , but i am unable to find its reason

Comment: Just FYI, there's an instruction called [`pusha`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pusha:pushad).  Making a PUSHA macro that does something different seems like a *really* terrible idea.

Comment: More importantly, this is not very minimal and is light on debugging details; I wouldn't call it a [mcve].  You haven't said what does happen, or what you see when you single-step with a debugger (e.g. BOCHS) to see which instructions execution reaches.

Comment: NB `$1f` is a reference to the next `1` label (also in the same macro's expansion). It is not a hexadecimal constant.

Comment: And the only use of KERNEL_OFFSET appears to be in the setup leading up to the `int 13h` call. Unclear how the stage is supposed to be jumped to at that position.

Comment: @PeterCordes i have added the output of the code. according to the tutorial mentioned in link1, it should print the string "Hello" regardless, if i jump to position mentiion by KERNEL_OFFSET

Comment: Please pre-process the source code (to cause all the macros to be expanded) so that people can see what the code does in assembly language (and don't have to decipher an alien language while debugging its implementation). Note that creating your own language from assembly macros is an awful idea because (unlike assembly language that can be adequately optimized by its author, and unlike other languages where the code can be optimised by the compiler) you are guaranteed to end up with "unacceptably poor quality" executable code that can't be optimized.

Comment: @Brendan Ok. Now , i have added the pre-processed source code

Comment: Please add the commands you use to build your program. Including the compiler and linker commands, and a linker script if you use one.

Comment: I think whatever your problem is related to your linker script especially if you haven't set it properly to use a VMA of 0x1000. The instruction `jmp *(0x1000)` I don't think is doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: @ecm i have added linker script and Makefile

Comment: Your linker script is setting `.stage2` VMA (virtual memory address) to 0x7e00 and not 0x1000. With that linker script you should be loading stage2 to 0x0000:0x7e00 .

Comment: If you do `mov $0x1f, %bx` it will move the value 0x7e00 to bx since that is where stage2 is loaded and the `jmp 1f` will fo to the same place. That is likely why that works. It appears that you have attempted to load to memory address 0x1000 which isn't supported by the linker script you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not your only problem, but your `POP_EA` will pop things in the reverse order from your `PUSH_EA` macro (the stack is last-in first-out), so will not match up:

```
.macro PUSH_EA
 push %eax
 push %ebx
 push %ecx
 push %edx
.endm

.macro POP_EA
 pop %eax
 pop %ebx
 pop %ecx
 pop %edx
.endm
```

since the last thing pushed is %edx and the first pop is %eax, you end up swapping them.  The pop needs to be in the reverse order:

```
.macro POP_EA
 pop %edx
 pop %ecx
 pop %ebx
 pop %eax
.endm
```

Comment: While this may be true, the way they wrote the code this isn't the real reason for their problems. The real issue here is that the `.stage2` section is placed at VMA 0x7e00 by the linker and he is try to load and jump to it at 0x1000. He would have to alter his linker script to accommodate 0x1000 as the VMA for the section `.stage2`. This is doable but the linker script has to be amended since the LMA and VMA aren't equal for that section.